# Script to dripfeed files

Tags: bash, command-line

I need to write a script that will check a directory for a given file type, say *.mov, and move up to, say, 50GB worth into another directory. The purpose being that we have a huge bunch of files that need to go through another automated system, but sending terabytes through at one time will cause a whole bunch of other processes to break.

Is there a way to restrict `find` to displaying up to a given total size? If so, I could easily `find /path/to -iname "*.mov" [halt at 50GB] -exec mv {} /path/to \;`

Or does anyone have any other suggestions as to how I can automate this? I suppose I could write a loop that added the size to a variable and halted if the variable got to a certain size, like (I'll worry about the syntax of the filesize test later):

```
TOTALSIZE=0
for x in /path/to/*.mov
  do (print file size > $filesize) && TOTALSIZE=`expr $TOTALSIZE + $filesize`
    if [ $TOTALSIZE > 50000000 ]
      then exit 0
    else mv $x /destination
  done
```

Would that work?

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact, I just smashed this out and it seems to work fairly well:

```
for x in $ORIGIN/*.mov
  do FILESIZE=`stat -f '%z' "$x"` && TOTALSIZE=`expr $FILESIZE + $TOTALSIZE`
    if test $TOTALSIZE -ge 2000000
      then exit 0
      else mv "$x" $DESTINATION
    fi
done
```

(I just tested with 2MB rather than 50GB but I assume it'll upscale)